# Assigning classes or ids to button created dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating several buttons dynamically.  I am trying to assign each on a different class or id so when it is clicked on it will have a different output. How would I add an value at the end of each class or id name to give each button a unique class or id name?
Here is my code

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data){
    var $contentWrap = $("#contentWrap").empty();
    for(i=0; i <data.length; i++){
        $input = $('<input type="button" style="width:200px" class= "button"/></br>');
        $input.val(data[i]);
        $input.appendTo($("#contentWrap"));
    }
});
```

Can I created an on click event for the all button that I created.  So far I created an on click even, but it only works for the first button.
Here is my code

```
$(document.body).on('click','.button', function(e) { 
    console.log($('.button').val());
});
```

Comment: Does the console log the same value for all the button click event or you say the console log happens only on first button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).val()` instead of `$('.button').val()`. `this` will refer clicked button.

```
$(document.body).on('click','.button', function(e) { 
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
socket.on('usernames', function(data){
    var $contentWrap = $("#contentWrap").empty();
    for(i=0; i <data.length; i++){
        $input = $('<input type="button" id="btn"'+i+' style="width:200px" class= "button"/></br>');
        $input.val(data[i]);
        $input.appendTo($("#contentWrap"));
    }
});
```

Comment: and use e.target.id for checking whether which is called

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: Is with this part of code `console.log($('.button').val());` The part  `$('.button')` selects all the buttons , But when you say `.val()` it defaults to the first one out of the collection. Hence you see the same output on all the button clicks.

**Solution**: Change the code to log the current clicked button value by using `$(this).val()`. `this` will refer to the element that triggered the event.

So the final line of code should be

`console.log($(this).val());`